# assigning values to first three rows of every group

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to code following logic in pandas, for first three rows of every group i want to create a variable which should have value 1(1st row), 2 (2nd row), 3(3rd row). I'm doing it like below, In the below code I'm not creating a new variable because i don't know how to do that, so I'm replacing the variable that's already present in the data set. Though my code doesn't throw error, it's giving me very strange results.

```
def func (i):
    data.loc[data.groupby('ID').nth(i).index,'date'] = i
func(1)
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have duplicated index, you can create a row id for each group, filter out id which is larger than 3 and then assign it back to the data frame:

```
data['date'] = (data.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1)[lambda x: x <= 3]
```

This gives the first three rows for each ID `1,2,3`, rows beyond 3 will have `NaN` values.

---

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3]})
data['date'] = (data.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1)[lambda x: x <= 3]
data
```

[image]